# uploading and displaying pdf file on the firebase storage using flutter web

Tags: flutter, pdf, google-cloud-firestore

I want to upload pdf file on the firebase storage in flutter web project using the following code

```
final path = 'reports/${pickedFile!.name}';
              final report = File(pickedFile!.path!);
              final ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(path);
              uploadTask = ref.putFile(report);

              final snapshot = await uploadTask!.whenComplete(() {});
              String url = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
```

but it always gives me an error in the **putFile** as[image] function and in the **File** function in the second line. So if anyone has a solution to this problem or have a suitable code for uploading and displaying pdf file for flutter web I'll be very thankful

Comment: could you share your import statements?

Comment: import 'dart:html';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';
import 'package:flutter_document_picker/flutter_document_picker.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer/pdfviewer.dart';

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are missing the right import.

```dart
import 'dart:io';
```

In case you need the `import dart:html`, you could adapt your code the following way.

```dart
import 'dart:io' as io;
import 'dart:html';

// You need to name the import otherwise you can't differentiate between the two File types
Future<String?> uploadPdf(String filename, io.File file) async {
  final Reference reference = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('reports/${filename}.pdf')
  final UploadTask uploadTask = reference.putFile(file);
  final snapshot = await uploadTask!.whenComplete(() {});

  return await snapshot.ref.getDownloadUrl();
}
```